# How can I distinguish between attachment types in exchangelib?

Tags: email, exchangelib

I've just noticed that Microsoft OWA does not display some attachments. Some people use images in their footer (which are attachments). I'm not sure if the only difference between a "normal" attachment and this emedded attachment is that it is embedded in the email.

Is there another difference? **How can I get only attachments which OWA* displays as attachements?**

`*` and probably most other email clients; I think I've seen a similar behavior in Google Mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those attachments have a `content_id`. They are referenced within the `mail.body` as `cid:[CONTENT-ID]`. The content_id looks like this:

```
cid:image001.jpg@01D3151A.F9036A80
```

where `image001.jpg` is the filename.

Answer (score 0):

looking for `cid:image_name` inside mail body fails for embedded images with src referring to a link rather than cid.

so the best solution would be to use `attachments.is_inline` property which is built in exchangelib.

```
    for attachment in msg.attachments:
        if msg.has_attachments == True:
            if isinstance(attachment, FileAttachment):
                if attachment.is_inline:
                    print("Embeded Image")
                else:
                    print("Normal Attachment")
```

reference: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/562